# How to handle Object from Array in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, object

I have a class nameed `MainActivity` which has an `Object` of type `Array` with the name `Amman`.

I made this object static in order to make it available to any class. When I call method `getEntry()` and handle position 0, I print `getName()` from class `Customer`. But, it prints `null`! Why is that?

My files as as follows: note : example of my code here [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzghc7agmsrr56q/Desktop.rar?dl=0)

**Main Activity:**

```
final static DLIST Amman = new DLIST();
final static Customers x = new Customers();
x.first_name(FNAME.gettext().toString());
Amman.add(x);
```

**Activity Print:**

```
Customers x = (Customers) MainActivity.Amman.getEntry(0);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(x.getfirstname())  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Class Customers:**

```
String first_name;
String sure_name;
String tel;
String city;
int id ;
String date;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTel() {
    return tel;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public String getSure_name() {
    return sure_name;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setSure_name(String sure_name) {
    this.sure_name = sure_name;
}

public void setTel(String tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return city + tel;
}
```

**getEntry** (in my Array Implementation level):

```
  public Object getEntry (int givenPosition);

/** Task: determines whether the list contains a given entry.
 *@param anEntry the object that is the desired entry
 *@return true if (the list not empty and the list contains anEntry), or false if not
 */
```

Comment: please share your entire code (Activity ,Pojo ) so that we can get better idea

Comment: post your response here.

Comment: post your webservice response

Comment: this is my code in rar file

Comment: [Link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzghc7agmsrr56q/Desktop.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine the problem has to do with the line of code `x.first_name(FNAME.gettext().toString());`. Your `Customers` class has no method named `first_name(String first_name)`. Does this not cause a compiler error for you? Try using `x.setFirst_name(FNAME.gettext().toString())` instead.

Also you shouldn't need to use `String.valueOf(x.getfirstname())`. Your method `getFirstName()` already returns a string, using the `String.valueOf` method isn't doing anything for you as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
ArrayList<Customers> mList=new ArrayList<>();
Customer customer=new Customer();

//fill the data in customer object

    customer.setfirst_name(" Name"):
    .
    .
```

and then add this customer object to ArrayList like this

```
 mList.add(customer);
```

and don't make your class static instead pass your arrayList to another activity using Parceable.

```
     Intent intent=new Intent(this,<secondActivity>.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", mList);
     startActivity(intent);
```

and on second Actitivy get ArrayList like this

```
 ArrayList<Customers> mList=this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
```

and get the values from it like this

```
 String name=mList.get(<position>).getfirst_name;
```

See [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/transfer-data-between-activities-with-android-parcelable/) example for how to use parcelable